# NirCMD - Command line screenshot with incremental numbering

Tags: windows-10, command-line, screenshot, nircmd

NirCMD is a free command line utility. I am using it to take the screenshot at a fixed time interval. ([NirCMD reference](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/savescreenshot.html)).

I am trying to get it index the image names so that it would be

```
img1.png
img2.png
img3.png
```

I found a way to get the datestamp, but cannot find how to add a simple index (e.g., 1, 2, 3 etc).

Here is the command line:

```
nircmd.exe loop 10 300000 savescreenshot C:\temp\img~$currdate.MM_dd_yyyy$.png
```

Can someone help with creating screenshot filenames to be `img1.png`, `img2.png`,..

I found [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785661/use-nircmd-to-take-screenshot-with-date-time-filename) on StackOverflow, but it is different from what I am looking for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I cannot find how to add a simple index (e.g., 1, 2, 3 etc).

Use `~$loopcount$`

> Execute a NirCmd mutiple times, in a loop. Between the command executions, NirCmd will wait the number of Milliseconds specified in the second parameter. You can use the **~$loopcount$** variable to specify the call number in the loop (from 1 to n).

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - loop](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/loop.html)

Try the following command line (not tested):

```
nircmd.exe loop 10 300000 savescreenshot C:\temp\img~$loopcount$.png
```

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted. Thank you so much.